# Why is it always undefined(when the request has no parameters and no geolocation search (lat and lng),it works

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export const fetchIataViaGeo = createAsyncThunk(
  'iata/fetchIataViaGeo',

  async () => {
    const error = () => {
      alert('Sorry, we could not find your location. Please enter manually.');
    };
    const succuess = async (position) => {
      const lat = position.coords.latitude;
      const lng = position.coords.longitude;
      const res = await axios.get(
        `https://airlabs.co/api/v9/nearby?lat=${lat}&lng=${lng}&distance=45&api_key=...`
      );
      console.log(res.data.response.airports);
      return await res.data.response.airports;
    };
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(succuess, error);
  }
);
```

This may be due to the fact that I’m returning it in the wrong place, but I don’t understand where it’s needed.when i try it without geolocation request,it work well

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning anything in your `payloadCreator` callback (the async function which is the second argument to `createAsyncThunk`: See these docs: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#overview

However you can't simply return the result of `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` as it always returns `undefined`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition#return_value

What you want is a getCurrentPosition that returns a `Promise`. See https://whatwebcando.today/articles/use-geolocation-api-promises/

You'll want something that looks like this:

```
function promiseGetCurrentPosition() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
    });
}
```

Which you can use as follows:

```
export const fetchIataViaGeo = createAsyncThunk(
    'iata/fetchIataViaGeo',
    async () => {
        const position = await promiseGetCurrentPosition();
        const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        const response = await axios.get(`http://example.com/api?lat=${latitude);
        // note that I don't use await here, since I already awaited response
        return response.data.airports; 
    }
);
```